# UTC date from variable serialized incorrectly in Apollo GraphQL request (GMT+3 timezone)

Tags: reactjs, date, datetime, next.js, apollo-client

---

I'm passing a UTC Date object to an Apollo GraphQL mutation, but the serialized variable in the request payload shows an incorrect datetime.

In my React component (in a **GMT+3 timezone**), I convert the local datetime startDateTime to UTC:

```
// Local datetime (GMT+3)
const startDateTime = new Date("09-13-2023 12:00 AM")

// Log the Local datetime
console.log(startDateTime) // Confirmed correct local time Wed Sep 13 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300 ...

// Convert to UTC 
const convertDateToUTC = (date: Date | null) => {
  try {
    const offsetMinutes = date!.getTimezoneOffset();
    return subMinutes(date!, offsetMinutes);
  } catch {
    return null;
  }
};
const utcStart = convertDateToUTC(start)

// Log the UTC datetime
console.log(utcStart) // wrong UTC date Wed Sep 13 2023 03:00:00 GMT+0300 ... this is not the issue.

// Pass to Apollo
createEvent({  
  variables: {
    attributes: {
       date: utcStart // 2023-09-13T00:00:00.000Z
    }
  }
})
```

However, in the network request payload, the datetime for the date attribute is incorrect:

```
// Payload shows incorrect UTC date
"attributes": {
 "date": "2023-09-13T00:00:00.000Z"  // it should be "2023-09-13T03:00:00.000Z"
}
```

The UTC date is logged properly before passing to Apollo. But the serialized variable is different.

My Apollo and GraphQL versions are:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.7.14"
"graphql": "^16.5.0"
```

It seems something during Apollo's serialization causes the UTC date mutation. Is apollo actually doing this?

I would appreciate any explanation that would help me understand and troubleshoot this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer you use the library `dayjs` or `moment`, both libraries handle the date very well.

In your situation, your local time zone is `Wed Sep 13 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300`, then the UTC date should be `2023-09-13T00:00:00.000Z`

Your time zone was `+03:00`, if you want to get UTC, you should deduct 3 hours instead of adding 3 hours on your local time zone

Comment: Thanks, you are right about the timezone. I will edit the question. However, the payload shows "2023-09-13T00:00:00.000Z" instead of utc. in this case 3 hours earlier.

Comment: "2023-09-13T00:00:00.000Z" This is the UTC, UTC date format always ended with Z

Comment: But I recommend you install the package `dayjs`, you can just get the utc like this `dayjs().utc().format()`

Comment: proper use of dayjs helped me fix the issue. I will assume apollo does not modify the payload during serialization. Thanks @fu-nian-wong, Ill accept this as answer.